# Can I fit a front rim brake to Vanmoof VM3?

Tags: brakes, rim-brake, front

I have a Vanmoof VM3 bike that has a coaster rear brake and I want to add a rim brake. What size should I get or do you know one that is compatible to this bike?

[image]

Comment: If you can make it work a front brake will be a nice add.

Comment: Did you chose a brake similar to in the answer, or a classic mountain bike v-brake?

Comment: @Matei V-brakes wouldn't fit on the bike pictured: it lacks the required attachment points on the fork.

Comment: I changed the front wheel and chose a brake caliper that is normally fitted to fat bikes. Alhonga is the brand, extremely cheap, however not very good quality. It was the only one I could find

Answer (score 6):

If your bike looks like the stock photo, then **possibly**.   However you may need new wheels.

There's a bolt that passes through the fork from front to back, just above the mudguard/fender.  This would be where a caliper brake would mount, and the mudguard would be "pinched" under the nut, on the other side of the fork from the brake mech.

You would need a side-pull caliper which has enough "reach" to get out and over the mudguard, and then down to the brake track on your wheel's rim.

This fork would not support a V brake or any other style that bolts onto a pivot below the brake track.  A caliper brake like a tektro R559 would likely reach. (not a product rec, just an example of the style)

[image]

You'll also need a brake lever for your handlebars, and an inner cable and length of outer.   I'd suggest looking for a lever that can clamp around your bars without having to undo the fancy leather-like grips.  They may not survive being removed and reinstalled, so a brake lever with a two-part clamp will make it much easier.

However, before you start, look at your front rim and figure out if it has a brake track or not.  The brake track would be silver or possibly black, but would generally be flat and just inward of the tyre.  This is a rim brake track:

[image]

I suspect your bike's rims may lack this brake track because it wasn't designed to need one.  If there's no brake track, you need a new rim on your wheel, which may require a new front wheel instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort!!! I did buy a new front wheel and now the bike has a front rim brake!